# Bitcoin Wallet Empty after importing using key phrase

Tags: wallet-recovery

I've recently tried to recover my Bitcoin wallet after changing phones however after importing the wallet using the 12 word keyphrase my wallet is empty (there was Bitcoin in the before). I've scanned the wallet for transactions but none are found.

Any idea what has happened and if/how I can recover my Bitcoin?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still have the old phone?

Comment: Which wallet did you use?

Comment: yes I still have access to the old phone, although the phone was wiped and restored to factory settings sometime ago

Comment: I've been using a bitcoin.com mobile wallet first setup in 2017

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what has happened and if/how I can recover my Bitcoin?

First of all, try to find out what software have you used originally. Was it a desktop/mobile wallet? What was the name of the application you set up the wallet through?
Please check out [this website](https://walletsrecovery.org/) and check the column Paths. If your original software wallet supported path like `m/0'` but due to software upgrades the new version supports a new path like `m/44'/0'/0'` or it's maybe a completely different software wallet that supports other paths like `m/49'/0'/n'` - in these cases new wallet won't show you any balances as addresses are being derived differently in these different paths.

If you know your addresses from a previous wallet you may also try the [Iancoleman tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), remember to use it in offline mode and I would personally not use it for bigger amounts anyway.